# How to save download file in network folder using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using following services file code to save auto downloaded file in network folder like below.

```
string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmm");
filename = @"\\192.168.102.110\servername\Shared\bbB" + filename + ".csv";
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(filename);
file.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
file.Close();
```

But it shows error:

> The specified server cannot perform the requested operation.

Aboe code works fine for downloading in d drive.. Anyone could help this..

Comment: It can be write permission issue. Ensure the user principal under which your website is currently running has access to the shared path. 
Are you running website under IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: i am running iis..

Comment: You are running under IIS and is website operating under App pool identity or some impersonated user?

Comment: i am creating service file it download in current system c folder but not download in another system